# Split sheet into multiple sheets and keep formatting VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As the title indicates, I want to split a sheet into multiple sheets and keep the  formatting of the original sheet using VBA.

There are many similar request on Stack
However, non of the solutions I came by so far works 100% perfect.

I would credit the author, for this great work, but I can't find the post anymore.
This is the best solution I came by so far. when copying and pasting it keeps "text formatting", however I would like it to keep the "cell formatting" as cell-width and cell-height of the cells as well. Any ideas of how to get it to work?

```
Sub Test1()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim iCol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter?", title:="Filter column", Default:="1", Type:=1)
Set ws = ActiveSheet
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = "A1"
titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
iCol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, iCol) = "Unique"
For i = 2 To lr
    On Error Resume Next
    If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(iCol), 0) = 0 Then
        ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
    End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(iCol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("ISREF=' " & myarr(i) & " '!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
    Else
        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    End If
ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
Next
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Update**

This is a minimal example of the sheet:
[image]

The provided VBA will result in 3 new sheets as follows:

Sheet 1:
[image]

Sheet 2:
[image]

Sheet 3:
[image]

**Solution**

I came by this solution:

```
Sub Test()
NumCol = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For c = 1 To NumCol
    m = Worksheets(1).Columns(c).ColumnWidth
    For Each w In Worksheets
        w.Columns(c).ColumnWidth = m
    Next w
Next
End Sub
```

After using Test1(), Test2() can be used, which applies the column width of of sheet1 to the rest of the sheets.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheet?

Comment: Of course, I'll update the post.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off by copying the whole worksheet, renaming it and using `AutoFilter` with `SpecialCells` to remove the unwanted rows?

Comment: @VBasic2008 It would probably, solve my problem, since it, now adds row wice, and can't include "cell formating".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PasteSpecial function with the xlPasteAll, which copies not only the values but also the format and width of the columns. You just need to say where it should start to paste.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(your sheet).Cells(start cell).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
```

I hope this ist what youare looking for, unfortunally i cant comment.

**Edit**

As it seems that you need xlPasteColumnWidths because the Textformat isn´t the Problem. That will insert the column width of the copied columns.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried adjusting the VBA and include the line, it does not work.